# 3D vector field from file, Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, graph, 3d

i have these datas:

```
x    y    z    vx   vy   vz

1    2    3    4    5    6

6    5    2    6    8    7
```

in .txt file.
x,y,z defines points and vx,vy,vz defines vectors from the points.
How can I draw it in 3D graph?
MATLAB R2012

i have more data in the txt file, it is just an example, how the datas look in the txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB has [quiver3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver3.html) function to plot 3D vector fields.
All you need to do is:

```
Data = load('DataFlieName.txt','-ascii');     % Data should be mx6 matrix
x = Data(:,1);
y = Data(:,2);
z = Data(:,3);
vx = Data(:,4);
vy = Data(:,5);
vz = Data(:,6);
figure;
quiver3(x,y,z,vx,vy,vz);
```

Note that your file should contain only numbers, 'load' does not understand heading rows.

Comment: I works! Thx! :) (I had to write in quiver command vx,vy,vz and not u,v,w)